# What happened to Google speech api server? It just accepts 4 second or less flac files

Tags: api, speech-recognition, speech

Any idea why google speech server does not accept flac files longer than 4 seconds?

I had a delphi program working very well with google speech recognition server.
But now I just can use it for 4 second longs speechs no more ...

Comment: Yes, they imposed a restriction, it's not that bad. Google translate API was free initially but become paid. Consider using other APIs

Comment: thanks for the answer. By the way, are we talking about the same subject? I am talking about speech recognition api, and yes I know translation api because I am also using it

Comment: Another thing "consider using the aother APIs". What does that mean?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Delphi (it's not asking about Delphi code at all, and has nothing to do with Delphi itself). I've removed the Delphi tag. Your question is strictly concerning Google and speech.